# Can I restart a side mission?

Tags: borderlands-2

I did a mission where I had to kill this insect and take its sample back to the man in Sanctuary. The insect died high in the air and dropped the item I need atop a glacier (there is no way to get it). What am I supposed to do? Can I restart a side mission?

Comment: What mission is this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to reload the area/game. When you return, the item will be waiting next to the quest marker or you will need to kill the mob again.

Comment: .....I'm gonna try it tomarr since I shut it off but every time I left the area/fast traveled, the quest item was in the same place.... waiting to be claimed. Maybe shutting it off will resolve the issue but won't know till tomarr. Thanks for your help budd. Much appreciated

Comment: I had the same problem with another mission, and it hasn't resolved itself through multiple game restarts, the target of the mission was killed and the item fell into water, where I can't get it, and it's still there.