# Making mutations on "Mighty Morphin'" mission

Tags: borderlands-2

The directions in this quest ("Mighty Morphin'") are really poor. I'm stuck on "injecting pods" at the waypoint area, but there is nothing to interact with. I saw videos online of fighting "mutated badass" varkids, but they aren't in this area, and the varkids in other areas just die. I don't see any pods. What do I need to do to collect this garbage for Hammerlock? (And, specifically, how can I make varkids mutate?)

Comment: Related/dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86114/mighty-morpin-problems-lost-mutant-badass-varkid

Comment: As a side note, the Varkids seem very vulnerable to fire.  There are those firemelon things all over the Varkid ranch, so it's a good way to take down the badasses, so they don't kill you in the face.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to visit the Varkid Ranch. Shoot a few of the Varkids there and run around a bit, and eventually they will stop and stick their face in the dirt. At this point they will start to form a pod. A big orange sack thing.

Run up to it and press [E] to inject it. Then you can wait and a Badass Mutated Varkid will spawn, you can then kill that and that's it. Just repeat as many times as you need.

NOTE: a Varkid will not mutate into a pod if it's by itself

NOTE: (at least for the XBox 360) if you kill the mutated Varkid and the sample appears, make sure you pick it up.  If you do not pick up the sample and save your game, then you will not be able to mutate Varkid in the future, so you will not be able to complete this optional side quest.

Comment: So this mission has nothing to do with the giant waypoint in the middle of the map?

Comment: The giant waypoint is the Varkid Ranch.

Comment: @toNyldaS: Varkid Ranch is near Tundra's entrance, unless the map's middle has the same name?

Comment: Just anywhere you see the Varkid nests. Those tall pointed tower things. All you need is Varkids really, nowhere specific. Just the ranch happens to have loads and it right by the zone entrance.

Comment: The waypoint is an area waypoint. It indicates an area where you can find the stuff you need. The large circle indicates an area waypoint.

Comment: If you listen/read the mission notes, it is mentioned that they won't transform to the pods if by themselves. And I've also found that they don't transform if you are looking at them. I usually run around into the middle of them, spinning around until I suddenly see a pod growing.

Comment: They will do this while you are looking. You just need to get their attention and then lead them around a bit. I run backwards, kiting them until I see the cocoon or sack, then I charge in and inject it. If you want some fun, do all 4 or 5 at once.

Comment: i think the giant waypoint is just the area in which varkids are spotted. it does not necessarily means that you got to go to the varkid ranch, in fact i injected a varkid just after i walked out of the tundra pass fast travel.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to damage the varkids a little bit to get them to turn into pods, but sometimes you have to wait a few seconds for it to happen. It feels like forever. Then, as mentioned above, walk up to it and use your Use button on it.

If you've already woken up Mordecai, he might kill the pod while it's in the middle of mutating.